# Unable to detect SD card (external storage) after disabling systemui

Tags: android, android-source, android-package-managers, android-statusbar, android-navigation-bar

I wanted to disable status and navigation bar on Android 9. so, I used the below commands do disable and enable both the bars.

**Disable**

```
pm disable com.android.systemui
```

**Enable**

```
pm enable com.android.systemui
```

But i noticed that, disabling systemui, disables the SD card. That is the SD card doesn't get detected in `file manager`. I even checked via `adb shell` just to be sure -
 `ls /storage/`. And i couldn't find SD card. Why is that? Is there a way to access/ re-enable SD card without enabling systemui?